# TopicCommand.alterTopic in Kakfa 2.4

Tags: apache-kafka

I have an old project (it's not mine) and I'm trying to update it from Kafka 2.1 to 2.4.

I have the following piece of code

```java
public synchronized void increasePartitions(String topic, int partitions) throws InvalidPartitionsException, IllegalArgumentException {

    StringBuilder commandString = new StringBuilder();
    commandString.append("--alter");
    commandString.append(" --topic ").append(topic);
    commandString.append(" --zookeeper ").append(config.getOrDefault("zookeeper.connect",
            "localhost:2181"));
    commandString.append(" --partitions ").append(partitions);

    String[] command = commandString.toString().split(" ");
    TopicCommand.alterTopic(kafkaZkClient, new TopicCommand.TopicCommandOptions(command));
}
```

It says that the `alterTopic` method of `TopicCommand` doesn't exist. I'm looking at the documentation and I don't know how to solve it.

I need this method to do the exact same thing but with Kafka version 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [Admin API](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#adminapi) to perform tasks like this.

In order to add partitions, there's the [`createPartitions()`](http://kafka.apache.org/24/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/Admin.html#createPartitions-java.util.Map-) method.

For example, to increase the number of partitions for `my-topic` to 10:

```java
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");

Admin admin = Admin.create(props);
Map<String, NewPartitions> newPartitions = new HashMap<>();
newPartitions.put("my-topic", NewPartitions.increaseTo(10));
CreatePartitionsResult createPartitions = admin.createPartitions(newPartitions);
createPartitions.all().get();
```